# Stiefel-Whitney classes as induced application in cohomology

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $\xi=(E,p,X)$ a bundle over a paracompact space $X$. We can consider the exact sequence
$$ 0  \rightarrow SO(n) \stackrel{i}{\rightarrow} O(n) \stackrel{det}{\rightarrow} \mathbb{Z}_2 \rightarrow 0 $$
where with $i$ we denote the inclusion map and with $det$ the determimant. So we can consider the induced sequence in cohomology 
$$ H^1(X,SO(n)) \stackrel{i^*}{\rightarrow} H^1(X,O(n)) \stackrel{det^*}{\rightarrow} H^1(X,\mathbb{Z}_2) $$
Our book says that the induced homomorphism 
$$ H^1(X,O(n)) \stackrel{det^*}{\rightarrow} H^1(X,\mathbb{Z}_2) $$
is such that $ det^*(\xi)=w_1(\xi) $. 
$$ $$
Why we can say that $ det^*(\xi)=w_1(\xi) $? In what sense we can identify $H^{1}(X,O(n))$ with the bundle $\xi$?

Comment: What book is *our book*? It never makes things worse to give complete references.

Comment: A vector bundle $\xi$ can be completely described by a Cech cocycle with values in its structure group, and one can always restrict the structure group of a real (topological!) vector bundle to $O(n)$ (on a paracompact space, at least) Such cocycles give classes in $H^1(X,O(n))$, and that is how you can view $\xi$ as an element of that set.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez But why $det^*(\xi)=w_1(\xi)$?

Comment: If you do not tell us what your definition of $w_1$ is, it is impossible to tell you. Using precisely that formula as a definition is a perfectly good way of defining $w_1$, for example...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez We have defined S-W classes with standard four axioms. So we have that $w_1(\xi) \in H^{1}(B,\mathbb{Z}_2)$.